# change chart position in pine script

Tags: pine-script

i have a chart for showing bull trend or bear trend. but i need to change chart position little down from top like 20px. can you help me guys?  here is the code

```
colorRibbon  = roc11 > 0 ? color.rgb(255,255 - 255/10*countBear,255 - 255/10*countBear) : color.rgb(255 - 255/10*countBull,255,255 - 255/10*countBull)
colorRibbonA = roc11 > 0 ? color.rgb(255,255 - 255/10*countBear,255 - 255/10*countBear,70) : color.rgb(255 - 255/10*countBull,255,255 - 255/10*countBull,70)

frameColor = roc11 > 0 ? color.rgb(0,255,0) : color.rgb(255,0,0)


if barstate.islast
    info = table.new(position.top_right,2,2,bgcolor = colorRibbonA,frame_color = frameColor, frame_width = 2)
    table.cell(info,0,0,'Current Trend:',text_color = chart.fg_color)
    table.cell(info,1,0,roc11 > 0 ? 'Bull' : 'Bear',text_color = roc11 > 0 ? color.green : color.rgb(224, 0, 0), text_font_family = font.family_monospace,text_size = size.large)
    table.cell(info,0,1,roc11 > 0 ? 'Reversal Bear Probability:' : 'Reversal Bull Probability:',text_color = chart.fg_color)
    table.cell(info,1,1,roc11 > 0 ? str.tostring(countBear*10) + '%' : str.tostring(countBull*10) + '%',text_color = chart.fg_color)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is to just add a blank cell at the top. With all transparent background and border colors. Then color your chart in the cells. I did that below, hopefully it's what you're looking for.

```
if barstate.islast
    info = table.new(position.top_right,2,3,bgcolor = color.new(color.white,100),frame_color = color.new(color.white,100))
    table.cell(info,0,0,'')
    table.cell(info,0,1,'Current Trend:',text_color = chart.fg_color)
    table.cell(info,1,1,roc11 > 0 ? 'Bull' : 'Bear',text_color = roc11 > 0 ? color.green : color.rgb(224, 0, 0), bgcolor = colorRibbonA, frame_color = frameColor, frame_width = 2, text_font_family = font.family_monospace,text_size = size.large)
    table.cell(info,0,2,roc11 > 0 ? 'Reversal Bear Probability:' : 'Reversal Bull Probability:',text_color = chart.fg_color, bgcolor = colorRibbonA, frame_color = frameColor, frame_width = 2)
    table.cell(info,1,2,roc11 > 0 ? str.tostring(countBear*10) + '%' : str.tostring(countBull*10) + '%',text_color = chart.fg_color, bgcolor = colorRibbonA, frame_color = frameColor, frame_width = 2)
```